# How to set caps lock as default in Notepadd ++

Tags: notepad++, capslock

Is there any way I can set caps lock to default on Notepad++? I am doing some data entry/notes and I prefer to have everything I write down capitalized. I constantly click the caps lock button between the two programs I use and would be much faster if it automatically is in caps when I click into notepad++.

I know you can make everything capitalize by clicking ctrl+shift+U. But would prefer to already be set to CAPS when I start typing in. Some may call me lazy, but I see it more as efficiency.

Thanks